# Trying to Show The records with the most recent Date

Tags: sql, partition

Im trying to use the Over Partition to create a row number based on SupplierAccountNumber then Sort by DateTimeCreated and then only show record 1. my current script i get an error saying Invalid column name 'RowNum'??

I have a list of email addresses for suppliers which have multiple addresses, i only want to pick out the most recent email address. Is there a better way of doing it?

```
SELECT plsuppliercontact.plsuppliercontactid, 
       plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountnumber, 
       plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountname, 
       plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountshortname, 
       plsuppliercontactvalue.contactvalue, 
       syscontacttype.name, 
       Rownum = Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountnumber 
                    ORDER BY plsuppliercontactvalue.datetimecreated DESC) 
FROM   alops.dbo.plsupplieraccount PLSupplierAccount, 
       alops.dbo.plsuppliercontact PLSupplierContact, 
       alops.dbo.plsuppliercontactvalue PLSupplierContactValue, 
       alops.dbo.syscontacttype SYSContactType 
WHERE  plsupplieraccount.plsupplieraccountid = 
       plsuppliercontact.plsupplieraccountid 
       AND plsuppliercontactvalue.plsuppliercontactid = 
           plsuppliercontact.plsuppliercontactid 
       AND syscontacttype.syscontacttypeid = 
           plsuppliercontactvalue.syscontacttypeid 
       AND (( syscontacttype.name = 'E-mail Address' )) 
       AND rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Try removing "Rownum =" and add "AS Rownum" after the over by clause

Comment: Or use the MAX aggregate. MAX(plsuppliercontactvalue.datetimecreated)

Comment: @Bobby both the ways are valid alias definition, what is not valid is to use an alias in the `WHERE` condition for the same query

Comment: OH right, I never knew that @Serpiton Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify with RDBMS you were using, but most of them only apply aliases **after** the query is executed.
One trick is to wrap the query in an another query that takes care of this condition. E.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
    SELECT plsuppliercontact.plsuppliercontactid, 
           plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountnumber, 
           plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountname, 
           plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountshortname, 
           plsuppliercontactvalue.contactvalue, 
           syscontacttype.name, 
           Rownum = Row_number() 
                      OVER( 
                        partition BY plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountnumber 
                        ORDER BY plsuppliercontactvalue.datetimecreated DESC) 
    FROM   alops.dbo.plsupplieraccount PLSupplierAccount, 
           alops.dbo.plsuppliercontact PLSupplierContact, 
           alops.dbo.plsuppliercontactvalue PLSupplierContactValue, 
           alops.dbo.syscontacttype SYSContactType 
    WHERE  plsupplieraccount.plsupplieraccountid = 
           plsuppliercontact.plsupplieraccountid 
           AND plsuppliercontactvalue.plsuppliercontactid = 
               plsuppliercontact.plsuppliercontactid 
           AND syscontacttype.syscontacttypeid = 
               plsuppliercontactvalue.syscontacttypeid 
           AND (( syscontacttype.name = 'E-mail Address' ))
)
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the MAX aggregate

```
SELECT plsuppliercontact.plsuppliercontactid, 
       plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountnumber, 
       plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountname, 
       plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountshortname, 
       plsuppliercontactvalue.contactvalue, 
       syscontacttype.name, 
       MAX(plsuppliercontactvalue.datetimecreated)
FROM   alops.dbo.plsupplieraccount PLSupplierAccount, 
       alops.dbo.plsuppliercontact PLSupplierContact, 
       alops.dbo.plsuppliercontactvalue PLSupplierContactValue, 
       alops.dbo.syscontacttype SYSContactType 
WHERE  plsupplieraccount.plsupplieraccountid = 
       plsuppliercontact.plsupplieraccountid 
   AND plsuppliercontactvalue.plsuppliercontactid = 
       plsuppliercontact.plsuppliercontactid 
   AND syscontacttype.syscontacttypeid = 
       plsuppliercontactvalue.syscontacttypeid 
   AND (( syscontacttype.name = 'E-mail Address' )) 
GROUP BY plsuppliercontact.plsuppliercontactid, 
         plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountnumber, 
         plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountname, 
         plsupplieraccount.supplieraccountshortname, 
         plsuppliercontactvalue.contactvalue, 
         syscontacttype.name
```